# C# IncrementalHash computing 2 records adding another record and when adding 3 records are not equal result

Tags: c#, hash, sha256

I want to know if adding 3 hashes to `IncrementalHash` and compute the result is different than first adding two hashes to an `IncrementalHash` and compute the result then create a second `IncrementalHash` and add the result of the first two and then add the third and compute the result as the following code shows I want to know the value of `result` in bellow code:

```
// first
IncrementalHash sha256 = IncrementalHash.CreateHash(HashAlgorithmName.SHA256);          
sha256.AppendData(logHash1);
sha256.AppendData(logHash2);
byte[] first = sha256.GetHashAndReset();
IncrementalHash sha256_2 = IncrementalHash.CreateHash(HashAlgorithmName.SHA256);
sha256_2.AppendData(first);
sha256_2.AppendData(log1);
byte[] second = sha256_2.GetHashAndReset();

// second
IncrementalHash sha256 = IncrementalHash.CreateHash(HashAlgorithmName.SHA256);
sha256.AppendData(logHash1);
sha256.AppendData(logHash2);            
sha256.AppendData(log1);
byte[] third = sha256_2.GetHashAndReset();

// result
bool result = second.SequenceEqual(third);
```

So If the above `//first` is not working what is a way to do this, meaning compute 1000 hashes first and store in a variable then, add the first computed hash for 1000 records and the add 1001 hash and compute the result, and the result is the same as when adding 1001 hashes and compute the result.

Comment: as far as I can see, incrementalHash makes no such guarantees in the documentation. But if you have written the code already, why not just try it?

Comment: I tried it now and the result is they are not equal, so my second part of question is how to do this?

Comment: Just append the data chunk and the hash for the previous chunk to produce the hash for the current chunk. Note that if this is security critical you might want to ask in the encryption stack exchange instead.

Comment: For SHA256, yes, it's different by design. Evidently, what you want is first = H(D1 || D2), second = H(D1 || D2 || D3). What you computed was first = H(D1 || D2), second = H(first || D3) which is completely different. If you had used `GetCurrentHash()` instead of `GetHashAndReset()`, you would get the result you wanted, as far as I can tell.